# High contrast theme & browsers

Tags: windows-7, windows

I like to use the High Contrast theme in Windows 7, not because I am vision impaired, its just simpler and helps me focus.

The problem is, I am a web designer and when I turn on the High Contrast theme all web pages look different. Is there a way to have the browser display pages normally?

Comment: Is there a solution to this yet? Firefox is completely unusable when High Contrast theme is enabled [for me](http://i.imgur.com/AFeJD9v.png). Although [Chrome at least works fine](http://i.imgur.com/e7uckLm.png) (i.e. it doesn't care about window's high contrast theme). So there must be a way for Firefox to achieve this too, no? Bump!

Comment: Here is the feature request to solve this: https://crbug.com/1231644 If this problem impacts you, please star this feature request and add your use case in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly Chrome works with high contrast themes too.  But Windows 7 high contrast themes wreck CSS image styles in Firefox 15 and IE 8.

You can approximate a high contrast theme with a modified Windows Classic theme, and then IE and Firefox will render the CSS correctly.  It takes a considerable amount of tinkering with the window colors to get a dark style to that works, but it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You can opt for Opera 11.11, even if you select contrast theme in windows 7, you can see the web pages normally.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox:

1. Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Content**
   (or go to URL `about:preferences#content`)
2. Under "**Fonts and Color**", hit the button "**Colors...**"
3. In the "**Colors**" popup, find the label "Override the colors specified by the page with my selections above:"
4. Select the list item "Never":

[image: helpful screenshot]

Comment: Don't know who marked the above answer as "not useful" - not only is it useful, it is the only good answer I found on the matter. Thanks Nebokad.

Comment: this doesnt work for every page . some web sites still stays in high constrast theme. ie:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663274%28v=vs.85%29